# Loading user control in Medium Trust environment

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I am trying to load a user control dynamically using this code:

```
UserControl homePageContent = Page.LoadControl(userControlPath) as UserControl;
```

I get the following error on the above line when the trust level is **Medium**:

```
 System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed. 
 at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
 at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)...
```

Is it really not possible to load a user control dynamically in a Medium Trust environment?

**Edit:** Putting DLL in GAC is also not allowed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you sign the DLL and place it in the GAC, it may work.

Although there is probably a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Its surely supported in medium trust.  I think there is some other problem.  i have used it many times

eg:

UserControl ctl = Page.LoadControl("~/COntrols/Control.ascx") as UserControl;

Comment: Can you please tell me how you could rectify the `SecurityException` there?

Comment: Don't knpw whats really it is, its supported in medium trust, but i think there is some other permission causing the problem